# Building a generator from a recursive algorithm

Tags: python, recursion, iterator, generator

I have a recursive method that I'm using to walk over a red black tree, and store various node information (in the list `storage`).

```
def _walk (self, storage, func, starting_node) :
    if starting_node is not self._nil :
        self._walk(storage, func, starting_node.left)
        storage.append(func(starting_node))
        self._walk(storage, func, starting_node.right)
```

However, I'd like to re-implement this method so that it builds a generator (from what I understand this should save both time and memory). What's the "best" way of doing that?

Comment: I don't think it's going to save you much - unless you are meaning to make storage a generator instead of a list.

Comment: gnibbler, that's exactly what I meant. Thanks for making me clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Begin by decoupling the action from the walking

```
def _walk (self, starting_node) :
    if starting_node is not self._nil :
        for x in self._walk(starting_node.left):
            yield x
        yield starting_node
        for x in self._walk(starting_node.right):
            yield x

def traverse(self):
    starting_node = ???     # maybe these are passed as
    func = ???              # parameters to traverse
    for node in self._walk(starting_node):
        yield func(node)
```

`traverse` is roughly equivalent to

```
imap(func, self._walk(starting_node))
```

or this generator expression

```
(func(x) for x in self._walk(starting_node))
```

---

You can reduce the amount of stack used by manually optimising the tail recursion

```
def _walk (self, starting_node) :
    while starting_node is not self._nil :
        for x in self._walk(starting_node.left):
            yield x
        yield starting_node
        starting_node = starting_node.right
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, recursive calls to `_walk` won't yield anything.

Comment: @thg435, you were not mistaken - fixed.

Answer (score 2):

```
def _walk (self, func, starting_node) :
    if starting_node is not self._nil :
        for x in self._walk(func, starting_node.left) :
            yield x
        yield func(starting_node)
        for x in self._walk(func, starting_node.right) :
            yield x
```